Can you find a real example of "time travel" caused by undefined behaviour?
I am curious. Does anyone know a non-hypothetical C or C++ counterexample to the myth that "the impact of the undefined behaviour is limited to code which runs after the line with undefined behaviour"? In other words I want to see an example of undefined behaviour "travelling back in time" and causing an externally visible effect. By non-hypothetical I mean an example of a real, production-grade compiler (preferably a recent-ish version too) violating this assumption.
I want to see an example where something is printed to stdout (or stderr) that would not be printed if the myth were true or where something is not printed that would be or where something is printed, but the text is wrong. Why the insistence on printing to stdout? I have seen some examples that use writing to a volatile variable as an "externally observable" side effect. I am not very convinced by those examples because I do not see how I would be able to actually observe those writes in the common case of a regular process in user-space (i.e not the OS kernel, device driver or embedded).
Edit: Yakk - Adam Nevraumont pointed out that writing to stdout is done via library calls that the compiler can not reason about. It occurred to me that there exists another form of interprocess communication that I think the compiler might be able to reason about - atomic writes to memory shared with another process. Unfortunately it sounds like interprocess communication by shared-memory is not codified in the normative parts of the C++ standard
The printing has to be done by code that is executed before the line responsible for undefined behaviour. I am not interested in examples of wrong output being printed after the line with undefined behaviour has already been executed. Note: since it does not make sense to talk about execution of a program whose behaviour is undefined, please insert "if the behaviour were not undefined" where appropriate when interpreting this paragraph.
Edit: I found a better way to word this: I am asking for an example that would demonstrate a difference between the real undefined behaviour "all bets are off as soon as the program gets an input for which the behaviour of the program is undefined" and a fictional version of undefined behaviour "the program executes normally until it hits the line that causes undefined behaviour and after that all bets are off". I want to see an example of the code that would have executed normally if the myth were true doing something strange instead. Code that goes "after" the bad line misbehaving in some way can be explained by nasal daemons under both the correct and the incorrect mental model of undefined behaviour and is thus not a counterexample.
Here is the closest I was able to find:
void bar (void);

int a;

void foo3 (unsigned y, unsigned z)
{
    bar();
    a = y%z;
}

According to the blog linked above some (unknown) version of clang compiles this to:
foo3:
  pushl   %ebp
  movl    %esp, %ebp
  pushl   %esi
  subl    $4, %esp
  movl    8(%ebp), %eax
  xorl    %edx, %edx
  divl    12(%ebp)         <-- might crash the program
  movl    %edx, %esi
  call    bar              <-- might be side effecting
  movl    %esi, a
  addl    $4, %esp
  popl    %esi
  popl    %ebp
  ret

I was able to replicate a similar assembly output in clang 3.3 on godbolt, but not on more recent versions of clang.
I believe this example to be a compiler bug. Clang appears to assume that bar() is guaranteed to return, but C has exit() and longjump() - the code after the call to bar() may be dead code. The behaviour of a program is undefined only if the execution state that does a bad thing is reachable.
Rules:

Include a godbolt link or an alternative means of specifying the CPU architecture, OS, compiler version, standard library version and other technical details required to enable others to reproduce your results
If your example does not use stdout or stderr despite the above request, please explain how I can observe the "externally observable" effect your example uses to demonstrate "time travel" without using a virtual machine, running your code on bare metal, attaching a debugger or using a disassembler.
Flush the output buffers. I do not find missing output caused by data being stuck in a buffer when the program crashes convincing
No hypothetical examples. I am not asking about what the C standard allows the compiler to do or what it could plausibly do. I would like to see a real example of a compiler actually doing this
No compiler bugs
Only C or C++


https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

@NathanOliver I have seen this one. This sounds like a hypothetical example. No specific compiler names or versions are mentioned. Only strange terms like "classical" and "post-classical"

A point about terminology: "undefined behavior" is not a thing that happens when a program runs. It simply means that the language definition does not tell you what the program does. The usual phrasing in the standard is "The behavior of a program is undefined if ...", where the "..." is the problematic code.

@PeteBecker how do you propose I rephrase the question to be more terminologically correct?

I may be wrong (I am not a language lawyer), but to my understanding the compiler may assume a function always returns, unless it is marked [[noreturn]] (or some compiler specific attribute).

I kinda like this one: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/60622 The UB causes code that should NEVER, not just before or after the UB, run to be run,

@AndreyBienkowski -- that's the problem with trying to reason about undefined behavior; it's undefined. That's not to say that your question isn't legitimate, just that it's tricky to pin down.

I believe this example to be a compiler bug ... there are no compiler bugs in the presence of undefined behavior. That's the whole point of undefined behavior, it allows compilers to assume things are true (which you as a programmer violate) to be able to optimize code (without having to solve the halting problem)

@PepijnKramer: Sure. But OP thinks that example is a compiler bug because the code in question may have well defined behavior even if called with z=0, such as if bar() calls exit().

@prapin: I'm not aware of anything in the standard to that effect. AFAIK noreturn is solely for optimization; there should never be a case where it's required in order to get correct behavior.

@PepijnKramer: Re “I believe this example to be a compiler bug ... there are no compiler bugs in the presence of undefined behavior”: That is not an example of a compiler bug in the presence of undefined behavior. It is an example of a compiler bug even if there is no undefined behavior. OP’s point is that bar(); a = y%z; may have defined behavior if bar calls exit or otherwise never returns, so the compiler was wrong to evaluate y%z prior to calling bar when it did not know that y%z would have undefined behavior.

"without using a virtual machine, running your code on bare metal"? Is there a third option? Also, godbolt does not count? Also, increasingly, even on single-user, consumer workstations code is more likely to run in some kind of VM, e.g. with WSL, let alone devops environments.

What keeps you from evaluating the volatile variable after the fact which has an unexpected value and print something? That is the meaning of "observable".

@Peter-ReinstateMonica "Is there a third option?" I meant that I want the example itself to be runnable as a regular user-space process. From my understanding volatile is often used in device drivers, operating systems and embedded programming to access special magic memory locations that are really a mechanism for talking to a peripheral device (or emulated peripheral device, if running in a VM).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica "What keeps you from evaluating the volatile variable after the fact?" Nothing that the process does after undefined behaviour will disprove the myth I quoted in my question.

@AndreyBienkowski "Nothing that the process does after undefined behaviour will disprove the myth": That's magical thinking.

Similar discussions have been closed as OT already. I wonder why this one shall be different. I got told several times, that UB may result in anything. Some things may be more likely (crashes), middle likely (ordering a pizza) and less likely (time travel), but the C++ specification does not care about likelyness either.

What is magical thinking; and why is Andrey guilty of it? His statement sounds perfectly reasonable to me.

@ThomasWeller You misunderstand the OP's use of the term "time travel". He doesn't mean the computer will literally travel in time as the result of undefined behaviour. He means that it is claimed that UB in a program can cause problems prior to execution of the exact statement that has UB. He would like to see a concrete example of this claim.

("Myth":) "the impact of the undefined behaviour is limited to code which runs after the line with undefined behaviour" Having UB is a property of a text, at compile time. And if a text has UB the compiler is permitted to generate code that does anything. This fundamental is lacking in your thinking that the compiler is in any way limited when given a text with UB. Similarly: 'real undefined behaviour "all bets are off as soon as ..."'--no, misconceived. Similarly: 'fictional version of undefined behaviour "the program executes normally until ..."'--misconceived, irrelevant.

When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?

FYI: May be relevant and useful: 1, 2. Quote from 2: "In general, any I/O transaction which is shown to be completed (observable) can not be affected by errors later in the program. This seems to be a desirable property!"

@EricPostpischil Have you seen 2? Any info what's the WG14 view on this "desirable property" (see quote in the comment just above)? Is missing of this "desirable property" currently a major issue?

@ThomasWeller: As a question about the pure abstract C language, "UB can do anything" is the end of the discussion. This isn't such a question. It's about the behavior of actual implementations. That may be uninteresting to someone who cares only about the C standard per se, but it's very interesting to those who care about the design and implementation of optimizing compilers, computer architectures, system programming, debugging, exploitation, etc.  That's the target audience of this question.

Perhaps some different tags would help clarify that.

@NateEldredgeWich tags would you use?

I removed language-lawyer, since the question is not looking for answers to interpret the standard, and added compiler-construction and compiler-optimization.

Here we go:
__attribute__((noinline))
void foo(int* data) {
  bool bsilly = false;
  if (data) bsilly=true;
  if (bsilly) {
    std::cerr << "This should not print\n";
  } else {
    *data = 7;
  }
}

int main() {
  foo(nullptr);
}

The output we get is:

This should not print


with no segfault.  We passed in nullptr, which should lead to bsilly remaining false and UB from *nullptr = 7.  Instead, the compiler generates code that prints to cerr and returns despite data being nullptr.
The use of __attribute__((noinline)) is to make it act like a function in a different translation unit without whole program optimization.  A dynamic library should work similar.
The "undefined behavior" in dereferencing a null pointer "caused" text to print, despite it never running.  And if you comment out the *data=7; line, it no longer prints "This should not print\n" when passed nullptr.
I mean, technically this isn't time travel, as *data=7 happens elsewhen in an alternative universe, not later.
In a "lie told to children", my guess is that the compiler deduces as follows:
If data is null, then we run UB.  Thus either data is nullptr (and we can do anything), or data is not nullptr.  Conclusion: assume data is not nullptr, thus bsilly=true occurs, which means we print to std::cerr.
The compiler used to demonstrate this was the clang-trunk x86/64 on godbolt; it is the development branch after 18.1 (leading to 19.0 possibly) based on the list of compilers.
I wrote it with the "elsewhen" technique to avoid the compiler not "knowing" what the IO code does; if IO code can run arbitrary operations, then reasoning about code after the IO code determining the state before becomes impossible.  So what I did was made the "undefined behavior" branch not run the IO code, and be fully able to locally reasoned about, thus causing "undefined behavior time travel".
You can modify the code so that it segfaults after printing if you prefer.  There are a number of ways, but you still need to pull off tricks, as a naked *data=7; won't trigger the branch analysis needed for the time travel.

int main is missing return

@AndreyBienkowski main gets an implicit return 0;

@AndreyBienkowski int main does not require a return; aren't legacy C-isms fun?

@AndreyBienkowski -- main is peculiar; falling off the end is equivalent to return 0; just before the closing curly brace. Weird quirk, intended to make it easier for beginners who don't yet understand functions very well.

"I'm guessing 18.1 from its compiler list": It would be the current development branch that will become the version 19 release eventually. But it works with 18.1 just as well.

@AndreyBienkowski I mean, it isn't really a myth; the problem is that std::cout io is opaque enough that the time travel fails - the time travel can occur whenever the time-traveled operation is transparent enough for the UB-based reasoning to propagate backwards over it (or, using my trick, avoiding the operations opacity in the UB case).  If anything, your request for actual std::cout IO is sort of cheating: on a system where IO wasn't an opaque external library, this is easy to demonstrate, but IO is almost always an opaque external library.

@AndreyBienkowski This is a tweak to this code where it's less ambiguous that the UB is strictly later in the code than the effect that it seems to cause: https://godbolt.org/z/T6WMhMW9P. It results in a SEGFAULT, but only after we see the print that should never have happened.

@ThomasJager Here is one with no bsilly, and clear time travel.

@ThomasJager: Your example can be modified to not use an else, thereby making the time travel undisputed: https://godbolt.org/z/1sG5h3ar1

I don't get this answer. This is clearly a compiler bug, not UB. The UB is triggered by trying to dereference the nullprt in the branch that should not be executed at all. What am I missing? Or is it showing the effect of nasal demons in case of UB?

@BЈовић There is no compiler bug here.  UB is triggered by foo(nullptr) being guaranteed to dereference nullptr.  The specific UB that this compiler generates in that case is print "This should not print\n" and return cleanly, which is perfectly legal compiler behavior: in response to UB, the compiler CAN DO ANYTHING.  The explanation of why it is happening is about how the compiler is free to reason about UB acausally: this reasoning is correct so long as your program doesn't do UB, ... so it is correct.  You can describe this as nasal demons if it makes you feel better.

How is the observed behavior inconsistent with that of a system where dereferencing a null pointer raises a signal that outputs the message "This should not print\n" to stderr?

@cptFracassa: How is the behavior inconsistent with the null dereference raising a signal that coincidentally outputs the same message as would be produced in the non-null case?

The only way UB can time-travel across an observable I/O observation is if there is a means of performing action which will always be irreversibly observable if executed before any other action, but which an implementation will not treat as potentially blocking the execution of any following actions that could invoke UB.  I don't see any such thing as happening here.

Great answer. The best candidate for accepted answer so far, but I am still waiting in case someone posts a better answer. I have made a couple of improvements to my question. What do you think?

@AndreyBienkowski: In this example, the behavior would be consistent either with a combination of time travel and nonsensical processing of other code, or with purely sequential execution of an UB-inducing action in a way that mimics some other action (e.g. by triggering a jump to the code that would perform that other action).  The explanation which doesn't involve time travel seems simpler than the one that does.  What am I missing?

@supercat "The UB can do anything, including emulation of other code" doesn't predict what kind of behavior the UB will do; it is a less useful model of what is going on.  "Simpler" only wins when its predictive power is equal.  The more complex description of "time travel caused by UB" provides (some) predictions about what happens here, even if it is more complex.  The "full implementation of clang and here is how it executes and proof it matches the standard" is even more complex and better prediction.  The trade off of simplicity vs predictive value is a real one.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont: If UB can't cause arbitrary emulation of other code, how would time travel result in the code producing the output "this should not print"?  In my example, the compiler generates machine code instructions that will raise a SIGSEGV if v is null, and raise a SIGFPE if x is zero.  The fact that code generates SIGFPE instead of SIGSEGV when both conditions occur is a result of code that would have would have raised SIGSEGV whenever it executed  traveling in time ahead of the store that would otherwise have raised a signal first.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont: In your example, what action is time-traveling ahead of other code, and by what means does that action cause the observed result?

@supercat the future UB causes the bool to change from false to true - time travel - then the code runs.

I'm unsure about this. One might argue this is not true time travel since you'd get the same effect by replacing the UB line with another one. I.e. .. else { std:cerr << ... }. The program seems to behave normally until the *data = 7 line is reached, at which point UB is reached and anything can happen. No need to change the boolean with time travel. By contrast, if std::err << "1"; std::err << "2"; someUB(); caused some extra output between 1 and 2 that would be true time travel. (Ditto for skipping output 2.) Would that be standard compliant, though (?)

As it is, this does not perfectly illustrate "time travel" because even without "time travel", the compiler is allowed to replace *data = 7; with a print to stderr since it's undefined behavior and it can do whatever it wants. But that could easily be fixed by adding std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; before *data = 7;, that way without "time travel" it would have to print "Hello World" before reaching the undefined behavior, but it doesn't.

@DonaldDuck The IO routines are outside of the compiler's local scope of understanding; you cannot run any code outside of the compilers local scope of understanding, because they could exit(-1) (or similar) and cause the UB to not be reached.  Regardless, "UB does anything" is a model that does not predict what happens, "UB causing time travel" can predict what kind of stuff can happen, and "here is the full source code of clang and the standard" predicts more exactly what can happen.  Use whatever level of abstraction you want.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont: What mechanism could result in the UB changing the value of a bool that could not just as readily cause an arbitrary jump to the output routine?  What's demonstrated in your example is that modern compilers that ignore the published Rationale to the C Standard or are hostile to the ideas expressed therein treat UB as an invitation to generate arbitrary side effects unrelated to the actions being performed, as opposed allowing processing to be agnostic to certain corner cases, with whatever consequences would result from such treatment, including time travel.

@supercat I explained the mechanism already in the answer above.  That mechanism  (UB acausal logic) does not result in arbitrary reliable jump or print instructions being injected into the generated code in actual practice.  "UB means anything" has weaker predictive value than "Current compilers will use acausal logic when UB would happen to move the effects before the UB happens" which is weaker than "full text of standard plus compiler source code and attached proofs" predicting what happens.  Your disagreement/annoyance with compilers is not my problem, I don't write them?

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont: If causality is thrown out the window, execution of code which has previously been jumped over does not imply time travel.  What would imply time travel would be the demonstrable failure of generated code to perform some observable action that should have occurred before the action that invoked UB.  That would generally require the execution of a load or store with side effects not anticipated by the compiler.

@supercat I mean, feel free to disagree, but you aren't convincing.  I have a useful model that has predictive value, and you don't, so I think I'm winning.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Does your model have predictive value, though? (Is there anything that you think a compiler can't do in response to UB?)

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont "aren't legacy C-isms fun?" - As far as I know, main not requiring a return is a C++ism. I'm pretty sure that behaviour was present in C++ before it was adopted by C, which only happened with C99. This answer hints in that direction, and here is someone claiming they witnessed Stroustrup introduce this.

TL;DR: The compiler is allowed to deliberately generate broken code if it feels so. This thing is called UB-optimization and it is too late to complain about it, we have to live with it.

@ruakh I predict this program int main() { *(int*)nullptr = 7; } is not going to print "This should not print\n" to std err on any mainstream compiler.  I predicted the above program would print "This should not print\n" to std error, which is why I designed it that way (it took some tweaking).  My ability to predict this is an example of why a model different than "UB means anything can happen" has utility - the UB acausal "time travel" model has predictive value, in that it produces predictions (accurate ones even!) that the "UB does anything at all" fails to do.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Interesting! So you take the exact opposite view of UB than most knowledgeable folks. (Usually people emphasize that UB can literally do anything, it's meaningless to ask why.) Fair enough!

@ruakh: Experts generally are not saying "it's meaningless to ask why", but that you're asking the question wrong.  If you ask "Why is the compiler allowed to behave like this?" it is meaningless.  If you ask "What actual behavior (that I see in my logs) is symptomatic of real existing compilers finding UB, and how/why does this code lead to that observed behavior?" you can have a useful discussion about the practical outcomes of UB.

This wouldn't be a discussion about time traveling without time machines:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*FluxCapacitor)();

static FluxCapacitor TimeMachine;

static int DeLorean() {
    int year = 1955;
    return printf("Marty in %d.\n", year);
}

void TemporalParadox() {
    TimeMachine = DeLorean; // This is ok, no one calls this function.
    abort();                // But let's be sure.
}

int main() {
    TimeMachine();
    return 0;
}

Compiling and running the code on:

Clang x86-64 trunk with -O3;
icc x86-64 10.0 with -O3;
icx x86-64 latest with -O3;
zig cc trunk with -O3;

all generates the same output:
Marty in 1955.

How? DeLorean() is never called because TemporalParadox() also is never called. Both are effectively dead code.
Let's examine the assembly code from one the links above:
TemporalParadox:                        # @TemporalParadox
        push    rax
        call    abort@PLT
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L.str]
        mov     esi, 1955
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf@PLT
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Marty in %d.\n"

In other words, the main() got statically replaced by a function that is unreachable.
Again, how?
An optimizing compiler is allowed to shuffle things around, but without violating any defined behaviour. But the code above already has UB (this is a given in any answer to this question), so I choose the example above where an optimizing compiler shuffles around the UB itself, to the effect of time traveling a dead code to before the start of the program, and by so, by executing a line before the UB source code line. Here is how.
The compiler sees there is UB somewhere, so anything can happen, including the compiler trying to optimize the UB away.
Should be no undefined behavior in the compiled program, then TimeMachine is assumed to be initialized by the time it is called. The only thing that initializes TimeMachine is one of TemporalParadox()'s lines, so in a well formed program, this line must have been called beforehand.
As TimeMachine() is called at the beginning of the program, the effects of line TimeMachine = DeLorean; must be in place before this line, therefore before the beginning of the program.
The compiler is lifting one of TemporalParadox()s lines but never calls this function, so abort() is not called.
Because TimeMachine is static initialized to DeLorean and not assigned to anything else, DeLorean() can be inlined in all places where TimeMachine() is called.
And by the magic of a non existing time traveling machine, Marty got back to 1955.
This is obviously an adaptation of Mature Pessimizations's Undefined behavior can literally erase your hard disk, and there is some points of note:

The impact of the undefined behaviour is not limited to code which runs after the line with undefined behaviour: there is no code running after the UB line code;

To generate the result, the compiler is statically running dead code, before the explicit UB line code;

Further, the static inlining is only possible if the initialization occurs before any program line even runs, so in a way, the UB line is generating effects before any program line, UB or not UB.


If you don't believe that the line TimeMachine = DeLorean; is time traveling, try commenting it in each of godbolt.org's links above. Because there is no way dead code influences live code, right? Right?
TL;DR: The mere presence of UB can time travel dead code into existence, before time itself, and generate impossible printing to stdout on various latest compilers.

Excellent answer.  Minor nit in wording.  Initialization happens only once in the lifetime of a variable.  TimeMachine is a static, so it's initialized to null.  The UB does not arise from dereferencing an uninitialized pointer but from dereferencing a null pointer.  TemporalParadox does not initialize TimeMachine; it assigns TimeMachine a new value.  None of that changes the reasoning though.

@AdrianMcCarthy: But the compiler is actually lifting "static initialization, followed by dynamic (trivial) initialization, followed by assignment" to a single static initialization by proving that no statement in the code could observe the variable's value in between those steps.  Syntactically, it's not initialization.  But after optimization it becomes one.

This might be too obvious, or not quite within the rules:
#include <stdio.h>

static void foo(void);

int main(void) {
    printf("Everything ok so far\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    foo();
}

static void foo(void) {
    volatile char huge[999999999] = {0};
}

https://godbolt.org/z/arTW5KxEn
You might think that nothing in the function foo could possibly prevent the message from being printed. But clang inlines it, and then tries to do all stack allocation in the prologue of main, which overflows the stack and crashes the program before the message is printed.
This might not technically count as UB. I had a recollection that the standard had something like "if implementation-defined limits are exceeded then the behavior is undefined" but I don't actually see it anywhere.
Interestingly, but unsurprising when you think about it, such code can crash even if the function foo() is never actually called at runtime: https://godbolt.org/z/eeYdrPY3G

https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#general-2.1 doesn't use the term "undefined behavior" but it prevents entering the clause where behavioral restrictions are applied.

Consider that foo is declared as void foo(void); and defined in another TU. May such inlining (leading to program's crash) happen at Link Time Optimization (LTO)?

Re: "not quite within the rules / This might not technically count as UB": hm, here user Keith Thompson believed / concluded that by omission (i.e. "omission of any explicit definition of behavior", C11, 4p2) an otherwise correct program that exceeds a translation limit (e.g. "65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)") leads to UB.

If an implementation allows distinguishing between the traps associated iwth different actions where the Standard waives jurisdiction, operations that are expected to be performed without side effects may be reordered across each other, causing the "wrong" kind of trap being fired.
int  *volatile v;
void test(int x)
{
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        *v = 1;
        int q = 1000/x;
        *v = q;
    }
}
void (*volatile vtest)(int)=test;
int main()
{
    vtest(0);

}

This is demonstrable in clang and gcc with godbolt; changing the divide expression to something that wasn't loop-invariant like i/x would result in the first access to *v being performed before the division (causing a SIGSEGV), but with the code as written above, the division is performed first (yielding a SIGFPE).

Followup: would refusing to compile 1/0 be the ultimate form of time travel?

@Joshua: IMHO, given that the Standard cannot identify any non-trivial category of programs that all implementations should be required to accept without making it unsupportable on many platforms where the language is useful, I think it should allow conforming implementations to reject any program for any reason whatsoever, with the caveat that quality implementations should attempt to be useful.  In some cases, having an implementation reject programs that contain constructs that can't possibly have any meaning if executed may be more useful than having it accept such...

...programs, but in other cases it may be more useful to demand that a program be free of such constructs.  The question of which would be more useful in any particular case should be recognized as a matter of judgment outside the Standard's jurisdiction, as should the question of when implementations should define the behavior of constructs and corner cases over which the Standard waives jurisdiciton.

Note that this only shows time travel if one views an implementation as specifying that a null dereference will raise a SIGSEGV aand a divide overflow will raise a SIGFPE.  The Standard does not specify any means of irreversible I/O which don't need to be viewed as capable of preventing the execution of otherwise-undefined actions that would follow them (if an action that would invoke UB is blocked from executing, behavior is defined as not performing the action).

I do not see how this disproves the myth I quoted in my question. If undefined behaviour only affected code executed after the line responsible for it, then after the line *v = 1;all bets would be off. It's a null pointer dereference, right? That is undefined behaviour. The compiler is allowed to do anything. Cause SIGSEGV, cause SIGFPE, enter an infinite loop or absolutely anything else - all bets are off.

@AndreyBienkowski: Many implementations specify their behavior in certain corner cases to a greater level of detail than the Standard mandates.  In order to uphold the as-if rule, the Standard essentially says that even if implementations specify corner-case behaviors the as-if rule would still allow them to deviate from sequential program execution behavior.

@AndreyBienkowski: The only situations in which UB could be observed to happen out of sequence would be those in which an implementation provides a means of I/O which is irreversible but is incapable of forcing immediate program termination via defined means (implementations may define volatile semantics this way, but are under no obligation to do so), or those which specify behavior in corner cases where the Standard would impose no requirements.

@AndreyBienkowski: Note that neither the C nor C++ Standard makes no attempt to recognize any meaningful concept of correctness or conformance for non-portable programs, and that certain tasks may only be possible on implementations that specify their behavior in greater detail than the Standard mandates.  What historically made C and to a lesser extent C++ useful in the first place was the fact that implementations would process certain actions "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" without regard for whether the Standard required them to do so.

@AndreyBienkowski: If an execution environment specifies how traps will be specified, then there would be two explanations for the observed behavior: (1) an implementation causes an SIGFPE to occur when performing a null pointer dereference, or (2) an implementation processes all actions "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" except that the division was attempted before the pointer dereference, despite occurring after it in execution order.

Can you quote the part of the gcc or clang manual that guarantees that dereferencing a null volatile pointer raises SIGSEGV? If the standard does not guarantee it and the documentation of implementation does not guarantee it, than it is undefined behaviour and all bets are off.

@AndreyBienkowski: I recall there's an option to disable null-pointer-related checks and optimizations,and treat a null pointer access as a load or store of address zero, with whatever consequences would be produced in the environment (and in some environments may be needed to accomplish certain tasks, such as writing new boot code at the start of a microcontroller's flash).  While gcc may not say anything about SIGSEGV, I expect Godbolt runs in a Unix execution environment that does.

Re: "wrong" kind of trap being fired": a quick question from experience not related to UB / time-travelling. The a-b may be implemented as ADD(a, -b) (rather than SUB(a, b)). Hence, in case of trapping the "trap info" contains OP_ADD with arguments a and -b (rather than OP_SUB with arguments a and b, which may be expected by the end user). Hence, the question: can OP_SUB be considered as "wrong" kind of trap?

@pmor: Platforms generally don't trap based upon the instruction being performed, but rather the nature of the unusual condition detected.  SIGFPE is generally used on Unix systems for Floating Point or other numeric Exceptions, while SIGSEGV is usually used for attempting to access storage at an address which is not in a segment that's addressable to the current task or is otherwise invalid.  If a target platform could e.g. perform a signed multiply be 3 using a "multiply" instruction with an operand of 3 that would happen to trap on overflow , or could use a "load effective address"...

...instruction that would be faster, but wouldn't happen to trap on overflow, it would be good for an implementation to specify whether it would make such substitutions, since in some cases it could be useful, but in other cases it would be more useful to guarantee that integer computations could never yield seemingly-valid-but-wrong results.

int  *volatile v; makes v volatile, which is a tad confusing. Does the same issue occur with int volatile* v;?


I am asking for an example that would demonstrate a difference between the real undefined behaviour "all bets are off as soon as the program gets an input for which the behaviour of the program is undefined" and a fictional version of undefined behaviour "the program executes normally until it hits the line that causes undefined behaviour and after that all bets are off".

This phrasing is somewhat easier than the initial form of the question. Consider this:
int value;
static void setvalue() { value = 1; };
[[gnu::noinline]] static void ub() {
    setvalue();
    std::unreachable();
}
int main() {
    ub();
    return value;
}

UB is triggered by execution passing through std::unreachable(). In a fictional version of UB where execution prior to that is unchanged, we would have value == 1. This is observed by exit code after that, but the actual execution and logic which changes is before. godbolt
And this example is illuminating for the general case. The cases of UB that are caused by evaluating some expression (division by 0, call to std::unreachable, dereference invalid pointer, etc.) can be assumed not to happen. So you can imagine these as if these evaluations are replaced with a call std::unreachable(). That is a correct transformation.
Then you can imagine any code that unconditionally leads to that execution is dead code and can be removed.
And that is why some of the examples of time travel are unsatisfying. Opaque function calls to functions in some other library could never return. In such a case, the compiler cannot prove that the bad evaluation will definitely happen. This can include standard library I/O and syscalls. (This is less true with LTO, which can see across library boundaries.)
So... it can be difficult to cause a different observation prior to the execution of the bad expression, but the actual logic executed prior to that can easily and obviously change and that can be observed in some less common ways before the execution (e.g. shared memory, smarter compilers, LTO) and in any way after (notably without the logic after being altered or incorrect).

I don't think this is a good example, because it's completely normal for the generated code to look very different from the source, so long as the observable results are the same. That's the whole point of the as-if rule. So here we really do want a case where the observable results are unexpected.

The observable results are different in the example, it's just that the observation occurs "after" the evaluation but with no change in the logic after the evaluation.

I suppose you would argue the hypothetical doesn't make sense then? Or just the deviation from "executes normally" must also be observable "before" the bad evaluation in the hypothetical, for it to be a good example?

In this example, isn't the return value statement executed after we've invoked UB by reaching std::unreachable()? So this could also be interpreted as the compiler replacing std::unreachable() with a call to std::exit(0).
